# How do I fix this loop so that the correct link is loaded and opened onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reddit

I'm writing a script to append the top 25 posts from reddit and have the respective links open in a sliding div below. Currently the script outputs the same post for each item in the loop. I understand why it is doing this, I just don't know how to fix it! Can anyone spot the mistake?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Reddit JSON array
var redditJSON = 'http://www.reddit.com/.json?jsonp=?';

// Define global variable for link content
var postContent = null;

//Get the JSON output from reddit and add to function "reddit"
$.getJSON(redditJSON,

function(reddit) {

    // Start loop of JSON data
    $.each(reddit.data.children, function(i, redditPost) {

        // Post data variables from Reddit JSON array        
        var author, ups, downs, url, title, commentCount, thumbnail, commentLink, imageNumber;

        author = redditPost.data.author;
        ups = redditPost.data.ups;
        downs = redditPost.data.downs;
        url = redditPost.data.url;
        title = redditPost.data.title;
        commentCount = redditPost.data.num_comments;
        thumbnail = redditPost.data.thumbnail;
        commentLink = redditPost.data.permalink;
        // Object containing content from the post URL
        postContent = '<object type="text/html" data="' + url + '" style="width:100%;height:100%"><p>image' + i + '</p></object>';
        imageNumber = i++;

        // Ouput image thumbnail if it exists
        if (thumbnail.length <= 6) {
            var hasThumbnail = '';
        } else {
            var hasThumbnail = '<img class="thumbnail" src="' + thumbnail + '" />';
        }

        // Output string    
        var redditPostOutput = '<ul data-role="listview"><li data-icon="false"><a href="#" class="postWrapper">' + hasThumbnail + '<div class="postTitle"><p class="no-ellipses">' + title + '</p></div><div class="votesWrapper"><div class="upsWrapper boldText">' + ups + '</div><div class="downsWrapper boldText">' + downs + '</div></div><div id="commentsLink"><p>Comments(' + commentCount + ')</p></div></a><div class="postContent"></div></li></ul>';

        // Append output string to div with ID Feed
        $('#feed').append(redditPostOutput).trigger("create");

        // Change background colour of alternating posts                
        $("li:odd").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)").trigger("create");

    }); //each
    $(".postContent").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".postWrapper").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".postContent").slideToggle(500);
        // Append post content into postContant div when visible
        $('.postContent').append(postContent);
    });

}); //getJSON
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WUgvN/

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: the jsfiddle seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I see different posts in the output.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, the content is the same when you click each link, the content slides down onclick.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used jQuery so I can't post a solution for you, but I can tell you that it looks like the problem is because in your `$.each` loop you are setting the global variable `postContent` to the content for each given post meaning after the loop you only have the content for the last post.

Because of this, whenever

```
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
$(".postWrapper").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".postContent").slideToggle(500);
    // Append post content into postContant div when visible
    $('.postContent').append(postContent);
});
```

is called, it is setting the content for the chosen post to the content that was retrieved for the last post in your `$.each` loop.

Answer (score 1):

As Loggie pointed out, although you set the value for the `postContent` variable with each pass through the `$.each` loop, you don't pass it as content for any of the .postContent divs until after you've exited the loop -- meaning that you're always passing the value the variable held after the last pass through the loop to those divs.

You could include the content as you create each div in your loop:

```
// Output string    
var redditPostOutput = '<ul data-role="listview"><li data-icon="false"><a href="#" class="postWrapper">' + hasThumbnail + '<div class="postTitle"><p class="no-ellipses">' + title + '</p></div><div class="votesWrapper"><div class="upsWrapper boldText">' + ups + '</div><div class="downsWrapper boldText">' + downs + '</div></div><div id="commentsLink"><p>Comments(' + commentCount + ')</p></div></a><div class="postContent">' + postContent + '</div></li></ul>';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YQkBS/

Comment: Doing it this way causes the each link to load when the page loads, even though it's hidden. I want the content to load when the link is clicked.

Comment: For that you'd need to store the values and call them with each click. I've put an updated sample up at [http://jsfiddle.net/MRLkA/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/MRLkA/2/) that puts the values in an array and sets the .postContent div on click.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much! A friend suggested putting the urls in an array but I just couldn't figure it out. I'm still trying to get my head around how this works but thanks again!